# What are x and y values after the invocation of foo()?

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 'hello';
var x = 'world';

function foo(){
    var y = x = 'hello from foo';
}
foo();
```

Is it x = 'hello from foo', y = 'hello from foo'?

Comment: go to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Add some lines like alert(x), alert(y), etc throughout. See what pops up. (or use console.log and view it in the console)

Comment: It's not useful at all, nor is it good etiquette, to ask questions of the form "what does this do?"  Perhaps you meant to ask "_Why_ does this code fragment output _this_ because I expected it output _that_?"  Or it may be possible that you don't know how to inspect `x` and `y`... that might be a different question. :)

Comment: Was the second line `var x = "world";` deliberately setting `x` again? Or should that have been `y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code, `x` is `'hello from foo'`, `y` is `undefined`.

In `foo`, you assigned `'hello from foo'` to the global variable `x`, and then assigned it `x` to the local variable `y`.

Comment: That is very interesting! I suppose that you could preserve the previous value of a variable before you did something to it this way.